# array.filter code explanation

Tags: javascript, filter

Can you kindly explain what will following code do?

```
shapes = shapes.filter( function (current) {
    if(current.id == dragID ) {
        drag = current;
        return false;
    }               
    return true;
} );
```

shapes is an array holding objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function name implies, it filters out shapes with id equals to dragID. Also, it set shape with id = dragID to `drag`.

So if you have shapes with id [1,2,3,4,5] and dragID 3, the function will returns shapes with id [1,2,4,5] and set `drag` to shape with id 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inefficient implementation of [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Imagine shapes looked like this:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

After running this code, if the item at "2" was the one that matched dragID, you'd end up with:

```
drag = 2
shapes = [0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Where is this code from? The author should probably be notified it would be better written as:

```
var drag;
for(var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0 && shapes[i].id != dragID; i--)
{}

if (i >= 0)
    drag = shapes.splice(i, 1);
```

If there's a polyfill in place for Array.findIndex, or [sugarjs](http://blog.sugarjs.com/post/14220007710/v1-1-3-array-findindex-and-array-sample) is on the page, it could be even shorter (by using findIndex).

Answer (score -1):

View this code

```
shapes.filter(function(current) {
 ...
})
```

as `foreach` loop. If function(current) return `false` loop stop.
For example:

```
for(i=0;i<shapes.length;i++) {
 if(shapes[i].id == dragID) {
  drag = shapes[i].id;
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would `filter` stop on `false`?